# Publish app Huawei Appgallery in the mainland China

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

Why is it difficult to publish apps on Appgallery in mainland China ? outside mainland China is approved but in the mainland China market is rejected. Huawei is probably puzzling developers of app publishing in mainland China. Is there a developer that has the same situation as me ?

Comment: hi dear,According to the team's confirmation, the reason why your app still not be released in China is because your app name is too broad. Please change your app name. The reviewer will send you a detailed email. Please refer to the email.

Comment: Huawei is quizzing us.  I repeatedly submitted my app but got rejected in China for reasons, modified my app again and submit again but another reason to rejected my app in mainland China.

Comment: hi NguyenDuc,just confirmed with the review team,your app is approved for publishing in mainland China.Pls kindly check, and feel free to contact me if you need any further help. :)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that AppGallery China has different app review requirements compared to non-China AppGallery, we highly recommend that you review [AppGallery Review Guidelines](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/cn/doc/50104) (Chinese version) carefully and make sure that you have meet all requirements before submitting (note: AppGallery China review guidelines complies with Chine government policy. If you are interested in the actual policy, you can find it [here](https://www.dataguidance.com/sites/default/files/china_draft_personal_data_law.pdf) but it is written in Chinese).

We note that your current app version (pending review) still has English version of Privacy Policy under Chinese language/region phone settings, China user will not be able to review and agree to the statement so it will not pass AppGallery China review requirement. Please provide a Chinese version of privacy policy statement.

Comment: Do I change the privacy policy to Chinese language ?

Comment: Yes, please add Chinese privacy policy for Chinese language phone settings

Comment: Your app is approved and successfully published in Mainland China AppGallery